# Is there convincing numerical evidence for this conjecture?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Theorem:  Every prime congruent to 1 (mod 4) can be written as the sum of two squares.
e.g.  13= 3^2 + 2^2
29= 5^2 + 2^2

Conjecture: Any prime congruent to 4, 7, or 8 (mod 9) can be written as the sum of two cubes of rational numbers.

How convincing is the numerical evidence for this conjecture ?
17 is congruent to 8 (mod 9). Can anyone show me how to find two rational numbers which when cubed  add up to 17 ?

It is easy to see that primes congruent to 1 (mod 9) can be written as the sum of two (integer) cubes.
e.g.  19= 3^3 + (-2)^3
37= 4^3 + (-3)^3
127= 7^3 + (-6)^3
But I have been unable to show that 73 and 109 can be written as the sum of two (integer) cubes. Can anyone find two cubes (either integer cubes or rational cubes) which add up to 73 or 109 ?
Why doesn't this conjecture say anything about primes congruent to 1 (mod 9) ?

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but here's a nice paper: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL6/Broughan/broughan25.pdf

Comment: How is it "easy to see" that any prime $\equiv 1\pmod 9$ can be expressed as the sum of two integer cubes?

Comment: If n is any integer then n^3≡−1,0,1(mod9). Hence if a, b are any integers:

a^3+ b^3 ≡−2,−1,0,1,2 (mod9)
Conversely if any integer k≡3,4,5,6 (mod9), it cannot be a sum of two cubes of integers. Searching among small integers meeting this condition, I found:

(2/3)^3+ (7/3)^3 = 13

Answer (score 2):

(too long for a comment)

Claim:  $73$ can not be written as the sum of two integer cubes.

Proof (sketch):  Say $73=a^3+b^3$ for integers $a,b$.

We remark that $$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$$ so either $a+b=\pm 1$ or $a^2-ab+b^2=\pm 1$.

Noting that $a^2-ab+b^2=\pm 1$ describes an ellipse, it is easy to check the integer solutions and rule out this case. [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+a%5E2-ab%2Bb%5E2%3D1+in+integers) is wolfram alpha's solution for $+1$.  There are no integer solutions for $-1$.

Thus $a+b=\pm 1$.  We can now take those two cases separately.  If $a+b=1$, say, then we need $a^2-a(1-a)+(1-a)^2=73$ and similarly if $a+b=-1$.  Easy to see that there are no integer solutions in either case.

Note that this argument generalizes.  If a prime $p>2$  can be written as $a^3+b^3$ over the integers then we'll have $a+b=\pm 1$ and it is easy to solve from there, or to show that no solutions exist.